# How many port number that android and ios have?

Tags: android, iphone, ios

I have tried google, but cannot even see a post talk about this. When I want to create socket in android, is the same rule of how we create socket in PC apply to android? Program listening at one port and wait to create socket?

Comment: Do Android and IOS support to listener to network ports? and how do I for listener on a port?

Comment: @FIG-GHD742 I think android support, just saw the ServerSocket class, should be similar to J2SE. But I am not sure what is the port number and how many we are able to supply.

Comment: Both of them (iOS and Android) support socket connection, but I'm not sure about how many ports it supports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `ServerSocket` and a `Socket`. Call `Socket client = ss.accept()` to wait until a client hooks in. Ff you are not sure which port is free just use `ss = new ServerSocket()`. This will automatically assign an free port. Also make sure you don't do this on the main Thread and declare the according permissions in your manifest.

Comment: 1-1024 are reserved. 1025-65535 are free if not used by third-party apps.